# What is the cause of this option chain anomaly?

Tags: options, option-pricing

### LAST CHG BID   ASK VOL OPEN INT. STRIKE

363.15   1.35    359.80      361.40    6          12          420.00

What's peculiar is that the price is significantly higher than the ask price. The question [Confusion about bid- ask- and last-prices from option prices data](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/50261/59432) is related and possibly my situation is caused by reporting error or an illegal interaction.  Still shouldn't the Last Price be equal or less than the Ask Price ?  More insterestingly, does this indicate something particular about demand (aversion) at this Strike Price in the option chain?

Comment: This is normal, the last price was observed some time ago. The market has gone down since then and now you cannot transact at that price any more, you can buy at 361.40 and sell at 359.80. The bid ask is current information the last price is historical information.